# Select a certain sda # to boot up ? Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux

I see sda1 to sda6 drives. How can I select a certain sda # I want to boot up  ?  Ubuntu 16.04

The grub has 2 menus and only 1 selection combo works and it is sda2. 
The others do nothing or bring up a Terminal for login.
 Thanks...

After the PC boots I can then select any sda # at the bottom of the File Manager sidebar and display and select folders or files in that sda drive..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those partitions have valid Linux or other installs on them, `grub` should recognise it. You could use [Grub Customizer](https://launchpad.net/~danielrichter2007/+archive/ubuntu/grub-customizer) to customise the Grub screen, and force it to re-search the drives. I use this occasionally and it works just fine, and I tri-boot Xubuntu, Kali, and Windows, so it definitely sees the partitions from both of my physical drives.

Comment: QuickfishFM...Gosh I will try it and report back.  Thanks so much...  Jimithy